# base class virtual method with an interface as argument cannot be overriden by an implementation

Tags: c#, interface, virtual

I have a base class which defines

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public virtual bool StartUpdate( Interface )
    { some code here }
}
```

Then, have a class that implements Interface

```
public ClientClass : Interface {}
```

In a derived class

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override bool StartUpdate( ClientClass )
    { some code... }
}
```

The compiler (c#) raises an error on DerivedClass telling no suitable method for override was found. 
What am I doing the wrong way? Why cannot the compiler take note that `ClientClass` implements the `Interface`?

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Found a "solution"

In the base class

```
public virtual bool StartUpdate( object o )
{
    checkInterface( o ); // if not o is Interface, throws an exception
    more code...
}
```

In the derived class

```
public override bool StartUpdate( object o )
{
    // o will always implement Interface 
}
```

It´s a mess, but the way c# likes it.

Comment: please provide the actual code with proper method signatures

Comment: why do you need concrete `ClientClass` will be a parameter, rather than `interface` ?

Comment: @marcelo - why use `object` like that? You lost all the power of having specific objects/interfaces.... This compiles but for sure not the way "C# likes it".... Have you even looked into the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

Your base class method signature is:

```
public virtual bool StartUpdate(Interface obj) { }
```

But in your derived class you wrote:

```
public override bool StartUpdate(ClientClass obj) { }
```

Even though `ClientClass` implements `Interface` it is not the same type. Your method's signature in the derived should be with `Interface`. From specification in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override):

> The overridden base method must have the same signature as the override method

---

If you want the derived method to have a different, concrete, type consider [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/):

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : Interface 
{
    public virtual bool StartUpdate(T data) { /*code here*/ }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<ClientClass> 
{
    public override bool StartUpdate(ClientClass data) { /*code here*/ }
}
```

Comment: I tried the generic approach, of course. But that base class has lots of interactions with another base class (not shown in my question) that proved unable to use generics. I'm trying to implement the MVP pattern (or something like it), so I developed a BasePresenter (the class I showed) and a BaseView (subclass of Form) because (obviously) there are lots of common functionality between the two. But I got lost with generics. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) It does sound like you classes are way to big. Break them down to small units with proper interfaces and composition. Then when needed use generics. As for the question itself with the not implementing the interface this answer gives you the reason and solution for it (even before mentioning the genetics)

Comment: Sadly, a Form derived class is not "breakable" (even if I split the code in various partial sources). The BasePresenter class is not so big. But the BaseView is somewhat convoluted. That was the reason to abandon generics.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely what you're looking for:

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T: Interface
{
    public virtual bool StartUpdate(T input)
    {
        // return whatever
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<ClientClass>
{
    public override bool StartUpdate(ClientClass input )
    {
        // return whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override a method while reducing the scope of the method you override. You have to accept all types of the Interface, otherwise you are reducing the functionality of the base class, which is not allowed. So you should write:

```
public override bool StartUpdate( Interface obj )
```

This is called the [Liskov substition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Using that interface in the overrided method is of little help, because I must to implement the interface in every class that could be handled by the base class, because it must call some methods defined in it. Please, see my comment to Gilad above.